# REST for PHP 5.1.6 for use with Backbone

Tags: php, rest, backbone.js

I am working on a project where I don't have SSH access to the linux server but just the FTP access to public_html folder. I am relatively new to backbone and want to utilize its full capabilities. However, the server runs on:

> PHP 5.1.6 APACHE 2.0 Modules: core prefork http_core mod_so
>   mod_auth_basic mod_auth_digest mod_authn_file mod_authn_alias
>   mod_authn_anon mod_authn_dbm mod_authn_default mod_authz_host
>   mod_authz_user mod_authz_owner mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_dbm
>   mod_authz_default util_ldap mod_authnz_ldap mod_include mod_log_config
>   mod_logio mod_env mod_ext_filter mod_mime_magic mod_expires
>   mod_deflate mod_headers mod_usertrack mod_setenvif mod_mime mod_dav
>   mod_status mod_autoindex mod_info mod_dav_fs mod_vhost_alias
>   mod_negotiation mod_dir mod_actions mod_speling mod_userdir mod_alias
>   mod_rewrite mod_proxy mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http
>   mod_proxy_connect mod_cache mod_suexec mod_disk_cache mod_file_cache
>   mod_mem_cache mod_cgi mod_version mod_ssl mod_jk mod_auth_pgsql
>   mod_authz_ldap mod_nss mod_perl mod_php5 mod_proxy_ajp mod_python
>   mod_dav_svn mod_authz_svn

Is it possible by any means to implement REST api on the backend? I have been looking at many frameworks in PHP but they mostly require > PHP 5.2  Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I use CodeIgniter with this REST add-on: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

Comment: i'm all for upgrading the bloody servers to at least php 5.3 since it comes with security fixes, features, compatibility and is future-proof.

Comment: I'm with @glasz. For the sake of your server security, you need to upgrade your PHP version. The [PHP release info](http://php.net/releases/index.php) shows that the last release of 5.1 was six years ago. Your Apache is also badly out of date. Security fixes matter: If you have a live site running on those versions today, it is wide open to being hacked. In fact, it may already have been so without you even knowing. If you're with an ISP that won't upgrade, ditch them now. If you're working for a company that won't upgrade, then your server admin and/or IT manager needs to be fired.

Comment: I'll also add that you're right; you won't find any current PHP projects that support 5.1 -- virtually all the major frameworks (Codeigniter, Symphony, Zend, etc) now require 5.3, and even the CMS platforms (Drupal, Wordpress, etc) tend to have a minimum of 5.2 (and newer versions will likely require 5.3 too). And watch out, because there will be some soon that even require 5.4. If you can find a project that still works in 5.1, the likelihood is that it won't be actively supported or maintained, and thus just as likely to be buggy and have security issues as the platform you're running it on.

Comment: If you're having trouble with `PUT` or `DELETE` requests then you want to play with [`Backbone.emulateHTTP`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateHTTP).

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick input. The thing is that am working for a very large enterprise level software which was built years ago on 5.1 . They have not upgraded it and it sucks. I don't have any other choice but to write my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, implementing a RESTful api does not necessarily depend on specific software versions.

[REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) itself is just a methodology basically describing how to use protocol features of http to build some sort of web service.

A framework only offers tools to support quick development of an api eventually complying to RESTful-ness.

So, i think you have two choices:

1. Look for a framework that supports your php version.
2. Write the RESTful api yourself.

Comment: The enterprise is large enough and upgrading won't be too quick. For now, I will have a single REST.php file on the server, and pass it data in this format using ajax:

    {
        function_name: 'project_users',
        data : {
           // data
        }
    }

I can then use GET/POST/PUT/DELETE to further simplify the behavior. I will try to match as much as possible, the REST pattern. Then, when they upgrade, it would be easier for me to map back to REST.